# Using Matlab's computer vision toolbox to count specific objects within another object

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, overlay

I have two separate images that are both derived from the same starting image. I want to essentially overlay the two and count how many circles from one image fall within each larger circle in the second image: here are some images of what I'm talking about:

**The smaller circles:-**
[image: The smaller circles]

**The larger circles:-**
[image: The larger circles]

Ideally I'd be able to track each of the larger circles and tag it with a count of smaller nested circles. So far I've tried using the radius of the larger circles and have looped through one by one checking everything based on coordinates.

This seems very expensive to do and I wanted to know if there were better ways of going about it.

Comment: Have you tried `pdist2` on the centroids of the circles? Do the black circles have to be entirely inside the red circles, or only partially?

Comment: @beaker They will generally be completely inside the circles. Also would `pdist2` act on both images? I don't know if I fully understand how it works - it seems as though it would be kinda inefficient as it seems to calculate every dist.

Comment: I'll work up some quick code to show you what I'm talking about. We only want to compare one point per circle.

Comment: @beaker I just noticed that it doesn't work if the matrices of coordinates are different sizes, is there anyway around this? Also thanks for the help!

Comment: What doesn't, `pdist2`? `pdist2` works for me for different size matrices (as long as they have the same number of columns), but then I'm on Octave and there are some differences. The MATLAB documentation also says that the arguments can have differing numbers of rows... `mx` rows for `X` and `my` rows for `Y`.

Comment: I figured out the number of columns with `permute`. What did you mean by "compare one point per circle"? Thanks for the help

Comment: I just posted some code. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's a simple way to speed up what I think you're doing. (There are faster ways, but of course they're a bit more complex.)

```
% Get the statistics for redDots.jpg
img = imread('redDots.jpg');   % You should really use a lossless image format like .png
gimg = rgb2gray(img);          % Convert to grayscale
bwimg = im2bw(gimg, .5);       % Convert to bw image (guessing at the threshold)
bwimg = ~bwimg;                % Invert the bw image so dots are white
stats = regionprops(bwimg);    % Find statistics of dots (centroid, area, bounding box)
redCentroids = reshape([stats(:).Centroid], 2, []).';   % Put centroids in format for pdist2

% Repeat the same basic procedure for blackDots.jpg
img2 = imread('blackDots.jpg');
bwimg2 = im2bw(img2, .5);      % blackDots.jpg is alread bw image
bwimg2 = ~bwimg2;
stats2 = regionprops(bwimg2);
blackCentroids = reshape([stats2(:).Centroid], 2, []).';

distMatrix = pdist2(redCentroids, blackCentroids);
radius = 38;                   % found from stats.BoundingBox
connectedDots = distMatrix < radius;
```

This just generates an array containing the centroid of each red dot, and another with the centroid of each black dot. Then it uses [`pdist2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) to calculate the distances between each red dot and each black dot.

[`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) also gives you the bounding box, so I just manually checked that to get the diameter of the red dots and hardcoded the radius. Any black dots that are within that radius of a red dot is inside. Here's are the values of `connectedDots` from my test run:

```
connectedDots =

   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1
```

In the `connectedDots` matrix, each row represents one of the red dots. Each column represents one of the black dots. So for each row there is a `1` for each black dot inside the red dot corresponding to that row. (If you want to know which one that is, you can go back to the `stats` structure and look at `stats(rownumber).Centroid`.)

To find the number of black dots in each red dot, then, you do:

```
>> sum(connectedDots,2)
ans =

   6
   2
   4
   3
   2
   1
   1
   4
```

---

**Alternative Approach**

This approach avoids `pdist2` by converting the image with the red dots to a labeled image. Then, when we've found the coordinates of the centroids of the black dots we simply check those coordinates (actually indices) on the labeled image to see what's there. That way, instead of comparing each red centroid to each black centroid (`O(n*m)`), we only have to check the value of each black centroid (`O(m)`). Finally, we use [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) to find out how many black dots are in each red dot. (You could also use the newer [histcounts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html).)

```
% Process the black dot image the same way as before
imgB = imread('blackDots.jpg');
bwimgB = im2bw(imgB, .5);
bwimgB = ~bwimgB;
statsB = regionprops(bwimgB);
% This time round to get integer subscripts
blackCentroids = round(reshape([statsB(:).Centroid], 2, []).');
% Get the corresponding indices... 
% Centroids are in (x,y) order instead of (row,col)
centroidIdx = sub2ind(size(imgB), blackCentroids(:,2), blackCentroids(:,1));

% Convert red dot image to bwimg as before
img = imread('redDots.jpg');
gimg = rgb2gray(img);
bwimg = im2bw(gimg, .5);
bwimg = ~bwimg;
% Instead of getting centroids, convert to labeled image
redLabelImage = bwlabel(bwimg);   % Label the connected components (red dots)

dotLocations = redLabelImage(centroidIdx);   % Get the label at each index
dotCounts = histc(dotLocations, 1:max(redLabelImage(:)))   % Count them up
```

Results:

```
dotCounts =

   6
   2
   4
   3
   2
   1
   1
   4
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused by `connectedDots`. What do the ones in that matrix represent exactly? (I know that they are logicals for a certain radius size) but is there a way to specify the number of dots in each of the larger circles  - (determining that there are two circles that contain a single dot). This is awesome, and it's much more concise code than what I had- I'm just not fully understanding the information contained in `connectedDots`.

Comment: `sum(connectedDots, 2)` will give you the number of black dots in each red dot. I'll add a bit more explanation on what `connectedDots` actually is.

Comment: @Sam I thought of an alternate implementation that could be slightly faster, if you're interested.

Comment: I'd love to see it.

Comment: @Sam There you go. I doubt it will make much difference in computation time unless you have a lot of dots, but it's another way to look at the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm implementing this one now.